# Add hpyerlink on dataframe in R2html

Tags: html, r, dataframe, hyperlink, r2html

I have a dataframe with  two columns, one is the name of FB pages, the other is the link of that page.

```
name.page   link.page
"FBpage1"   "http://facebook/FBpage1"
"FBpage2"   "http://facebook/FBpage2"
"FBpage3"   "http://facebook/FBpage3"
"FBpage4"   "http://facebook/FBpage4"
```

and I want the output will be only the name.page with hyperlink, so I can click the page name and link to that FBpage.

```
name.page
"FBpage1"
"FBpage2"
"FBpage3"
"FBpage4"
```

I am using R2HTML but don't know how to do it,
any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using the `R2html` package, but basically what I gather is that you need a way to generate the markup for each link so that within the table there is a direct link to the page? For demonstrtion purposes im using `htmltools` and `knitr` to accomplish this.

## PS please use `dput` so we can more easily reproduce your data in the future:

the part that produces the markup is in the pipe ...
        read.table(
    textConnection('name.page   link.page
                    "FBpage1"   "http://facebook/FBpage1"
                    "FBpage2"   "http://facebook/FBpage2"
                    "FBpage3"   "http://facebook/FBpage3"
                    "FBpage4"   "http://facebook/FBpage4"')) %>% {
                   colnames(.) <- as.character(.[1,])
                   .[-1,] %>% mutate(
                       link_display = 
                           sprintf('%s', link.page, name.page)
                   ) %>% 
                       knitr::kable(., format = "html", escape = FALSE) %>% 
                       htmltools::HTML() %>% 
                       htmltools::html_print()
               }

So using `sprintf` I placed the link in the `href` attribute which is the html markup command for creating an external link and then used the name column as the display text which results in: [image]